# A web app that allows me to paste an image copied into clipboard?

Tags: webapp-rec

Basically, whenever I have a screenshot that I would need to upload onto the net, I often have to do this:

1. Do a screenshot;
2. Open an editor (like Paint);
3. Paste image and save (to desktop)
4. Go to imgur.com and upload it
5. Copy the URL (ta-da)
6. Go to desktop and delete the screenshot

Basically, I'm looking for a webapp that allows me to do these steps more easily, as such:

1. Take a screenshot
2. Go to that-imba-app.com
3. Paste image and click submit
4. Copy the URL (ta-da)

Is there such an app (web app, of course)?

Comment: imgur now supports simply pasting the image from the clipboard (I use FF 20 and it works already since a few weeks). Essentially it works like what you were looking forward.

Comment: @mark, However it doesn't allow clipping to remove off unimportant parts. That is achievable with ScreenShootMe

Comment: true. But then I didn't read anywhere anyone asking for it :)

Comment: [Pasteboard](http://www.pasteboard.co) by Joel Besada works usually nicely on Firefox — except when it deletes an image ! —. Alas, it does not work on Safari Mac neither on Safari iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ScreenShootMe](http://screenshoot.me/) does exactly what you want.

You can:

- take any image from your clipboard
- click the "Paste" button and it will appear on the web app
- click "Save" and it will generate a URL that points to your image

It will either create a random URL or you can create a custom name for your URL.

Comment: this is good but is there a solution which uses javascript instead of java? when i visit the page the lag on my box is insignificantly significant

Comment: @Pacerier: I wouldn't have thought so as pasting an image in to a browser isn't really "normal".  I would have thought that you would need the Java (or Flash) plugin to interact with the OS. you could try out [iClippy](http://iclippy.com/) instead. It's a desktop installation so not really on-topic here.

Comment: Nowadays, modern browsers have HTML5 APIs that allow pasting images directly from clipboard. For this reason, and because ScreenShotMe requires a plugin, I believe this answer is not the best anymore.

Comment: This asks for Java.

Comment: I would like to add two more options alongside https://snag.gy and https://pasteboard.co, they are https://onpaste.com and https://paste.pics

Answer (score 3):

### [snag.gy](http://snag.gy/)

[Snaggy](http://snag.gy/) does exactly that, is very easy to use and has a simple editor to crop and annotate the image. On modern browsers, it can paste the image directly from clipboard using HTML5, no plugins are required. On older browsers, a Java plugin is still needed. ([FAQ](http://snag.gy/faq))

Comment: Does anyone know (or can link to info on) how snaggy works?

Comment: This site is nice… except that [it says that it deletes unviewed images after 6 months](http://snag.gy/terms).

Answer (score 2):

### [Min.us](http://min.us)

I'm using [Min.us](http://min.us)'s chrome extension (ff available), which does a pretty good job of this. They have a desktop application as well (cross platform) which allows you to take a screenshot and copy its url directly.

If the screenshot pertains to a website (inside browser) I'd say go for the extension. Otherwise use the desktop application

Also there's something for Dropbox, called [Dropbox Screen Grabber], which automatically takes a full-screen screenshot, copies it to the dropbox public folder, and copies the public url.

I'm not so sure if either of them offers a cliboard version, though. Min.us has an API, so there should be something imo.

Comment: thx for the info, though i was looking for a solution that i can use on any computer without installling any programs or browser-plugins  .

Comment: I've put in a suggestion to the min.us team for the Clipboard option. They said `its a bit difficult to implement due to brwoser limitations. We'll try however`

Comment: link to chrome extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/awesome-screenshot-minus/bnophbnknjcjnbadhhkciahanapffepm?hl=en, the website min.us is down though.

Comment: Page not found on chrome webstore. Maybe the addon is dead.

Answer (score 0):

### [pasteboard.co](http://pasteboard.co/)

[Pasteboard](http://pasteboard.co/) can paste images from the clipboard, via drag-and-drop, or capture from the webcam. The image can be cropped before uploading. It uses recent APIs from modern browsers, no plugins are required. The [source-code is available on GitHub](https://github.com/JoelBesada/pasteboard).

The service returns a URL to the page containing the image. Image hotlinking is disabled, though. Also note that the images are deleted after 90 days.

Comment: There's no provided direct link to the image. Then what's the point.

Comment: Updated the answer with some more notes.

Comment: This site is very nice… except when it deletes the image.

Comment: Alas, this site does not work on Safari Mac.